# Opaque type and index signatures

Tags: typescript, types

It seems the common way to make an opaque type is something like the following:

```
declare const sym: unique symbol;
type O = { [sym]: true };
```

(note that this type is totally opaque, not branded).

This works in a sense that nothing else can be assigned to type O.  However suppose, I have an index signature type (or Record):

```
type T = { [key: string]: number };
```

The problem is that type O is assignable to type T:

```
const o: O = {} as O;
const t: T = o; // no error
```

I guess this is because type T includes empty object {} and instance of O is assignable to that.  Ideally I would prefer type O not to be assignable to anything, other than itself (and any).  Is there any other way to declare opaque type to achieve this?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "nothing else can be assigned to type `O`" or "`O` should not be assignable to anything other than itself and `any`". It is trivial to produce types like `O & Something` which will be assignable to type `O` and to produce types like `O | Something` which `O` will be assignable to.  `never` is always assignable to `O`, and `O` is always assignable to `unknown`.   I must be misunderstanding what you're looking for.

Comment: Oh i see, yeah, O will be assignable to types like O | Something and unknown.  I guess i meant that if there is a type like T above which is unrelated to O, then O should not be assignable to it.  I checked e.g. if T is a class, then O is not assignable to T, but if T is just a record or an index signature then I don't know how to avoid this.

Comment: `T` is as "related" to `O` as `unknown` is related to `O`.  They're both supertypes.  Possibly you could add a string index signature to `O` saying that any value at a string key must be `undefined`, as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/mblv4w), but without some understanding of your use cases I wouldn't know whether that's a good idea or not, and you're not going to be able to prevent supertypes, whether or not you think of them as being "related".  How can we proceed here?

Comment: Oh I see, this actually works, thanks!  The only problem was that if type T index signature values include undefined (e.g. type T = { [key: string]: number | undefined } it wouldn't work.  But I changed undefined to unknown and now it works in this case too.  I guess it's because unknown cannot be assigned to another type.   You can post the answer if you'd like.  I don't see any other problems with this so far, since it would not enable assignment in other direction (because of unique sym).

Comment: Right, `unknown` might work better for your use cases (of course then `type T = {[k: string]: unknown}` will still work but that's very close to a universal supertype anyway so maybe you don't care?)  I'll post an answer when I get a chance.

Comment: Yeah, i also noticed it would not work for case type t = {[k: string]: any }, I m not using this though in my case (of course it would be nice if there is a solution for this too, but that's ok).  Also, it seems that if in the definition of type O we use PropertyKey instead of string to make it more general it still generates the error correctly ([k: PropertyKey]: unknown) unless i m missing something.

Comment: Should I let you write up your own answer? You're the one who understands your use cases and I'm not really sure what the goal is, since there will always be supertypes and subtypes of just about anything.

Comment: Sure, it's up to you, i can post it too.  I guess the goal is to have something as close as possible to nominal typing for opaque type.  This would prevent user from accidentally assigning an instance of opaque type to some other variable that does not explicitly allow such instances.  As you mentioned, if the user has a variable of type like (O | Something), then O would be assignable to that, but that's fine since since the user declared such an intention.  Also type O will be assignable to unknown or any, which is also fine.  Not sure if there are any other cases that were not considered.

Answer (score 0):

As was suggested in the comments, the way to disallow an opaque type O to be assigned to an index signature type is to add index signature to the opaque type:

```
declare const sym: unique symbol;
type O = {
  [sym]: true;
  [key: PropertyKey]: unknown;
};
```

In this case if our target type T has an index signature that cannot be assigned to from type O, the assignment from O to T will be disallowed:

```
type T = { [key: string]: number; }
const o: O = {} as O;
const t: T = o; // Error: index signatures are incompatible
```

Note that this will not work (will not trigger error) if the signature type in O is assignable to the one in T, e.g if

```
T = { [key: string]: unknown }
```

or

```
T = { [key: string]: any }
```

So this is only partial solution to prevent assignability of an opaque type.